# Can linear regression be used to solve this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
    2015        2016        2017        2018        2019    
Jan 10991273    15761628    20702648    28836397    32462658
Feb 11910590    18407640    21867727    29592821    34120748
Mar 14720817    22353179    28631090    37017871    41731600
Apr 14240928    22383817    28698805    36719286    40352427
May 13999937    22562954    30105567    38492879    42443240
Jun 14618367    23485559    31294015    40219835    42243535
Jul 16954514    22816656    31235203    39633588    41259052
Aug 16384802    22418011    30851292    39153646    38739977
Sep 17546431    22387746    30207602    37501028    37273751
Oct 19069836    24623265    34346016    42694615    0
Nov 15864435    21323086    30132954    34682955    0
Dec 14728914    18795856    26990426    33064396    0
```

Essentially I'm trying to predict those zero values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


lm = LinearRegression()

Z = df[['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018']]

lm.fit(Z , df['2019'])

y_predict = lm.predict(Z)

print(y_predict)
```

And the output is this:

```
array([31915988.349427  , 42517368.34239061, 42188302.01643895,
       40885793.12471981, 39423851.45561062, 43649973.20909937,
       29415292.34136068, 28706985.92182099, 21561488.69575803,
       24801192.93635751,  -508990.40716472,  6069742.01418072])
```

Does that output represent a prediction of those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it does *not*.

The lack of agreement with the earlier values for Jan-Sep is a bad sign.

The large negative value for Nov suggests that there's something wrong. What do these numbers represent?  Is a negative value physically possible?

It's a mistake to treat a function like a black box.

I could look at this data in different ways:

1. One fit per month where year is the input value.
2. One fit per year, with 12 values total.
3. A 2D surface with month, year as parameters.

Which one are you doing?  What order fit are you assuming?

You should be able to calculate SSE and figure out goodness of fit for different schemes.

I would urge you to plot the data and look at it before you try to fit anything.  Understand the data better.

Comment: The only decent answer. Thanks.